# Magento2: Can we add range slider on product attribute:DropDown

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

Hi can we add range slider on layer navigation on product attribute Drop-drown selection. In current magenro2 provide same range slider but on product attribute "price".
I have requirement range slider on color attribute.

[image]
I want same range slider on my custom attribute. Dropdown:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add that, In-fact i have worked on one such extension but it would require lots of modification and to describe here is not possible. But for a hint i can tell you the way, you need to change in layout first to set your slider then in corresponding phtml file you can get the range for your custom attribute (will get the range with attribute id [from drop-down options]) and you would require plenty of JS work too. One function would be there for slider functionality which is not much hectic but magento filter the products based on range for price type attribute so you need to adjust your custom attribute functionality for that as well.

I tried my best to give you the hint as much as possible as its very vast and you need to take care lot of things for this. you will get reference for the same to some extent on internet though.